# Push child array of objects into parent array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a parent array `lines = []` and contains a number of objects in `lines.push(data);` . The data is read line by line in my node application.
And i split each line whenever `\` slash character is found. Then change line into Objects `data = {}` and properties `data.marker; data.value; data.children` and so. Now when a line which has several `\` slash characters is found i want that `data.children`  to be a child array of objects. 
This is the line data after `split()`

```
    [ 'ft Some older versions read, ',
      'fqa And we are writing these things to you so that your joy will be complete. ',
      'fqb  ',
      'f*' ]
```

and this is my code to convert into `data.children` array

```
    data.children = [];
    //object for child
    var obj = {};
    for (var j=0; j<childArr.length; j++) {
        obj.marker = childArr[j].split(" ")[0] ;
        obj.value = childArr[j].substr(childArr[j].indexOf(' ')+1) ;                           
    }
    data.children.push(obj);
```

Now when i check `console.log(data.children)` this is what i gets

```
    [ { marker: 'f*', value: 'f*' }]
```

instead of what i need is

```
    [ { marker: 'ft' , value: 'Some older versions read,' },
      { marker: 'fqa', value: 'And we are writing these things to you so that your joy will be complete.' },
      { marker: 'fqb', value: 'null' },
      { marker: 'f*', value: 'null' },]
```

I am sure that it will be some trouble while i am pushing data into children array. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's because you're pushing after the loop;

add the push within your for loop

Comment: Sorry to say but i tried pushing child array with in the loop then also i am getting the same like `{ marker: 'f*', value: 'f*' }`

Comment: you're changing properties of `obj` ... but it is the same `obj` every time you push ... you need to create a new object every iteration ... @War's answer is 90% correct ... a couple `=` should be `:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right answer i needed. Sorry for posting it very lately and appreciate all of your efforts. Thank you.

```
data.children = [];
```

```js
var childArr = [ 'ft Some older versions read, ',
      'fqa And we are writing these things to you so that your joy will be complete. ',
      'fqb  ',
      'f*' ];

var data = {};
data.children = [];
for (var j = 0; j < childArr.length; j++) {
  let split = childArr[j].split(" ");
  data.children.push({
     marker: split[0],
     value: ((split[1] == "" ||split[1] == undefined) ? null : split.slice(1).join(" "))
  });
}
console.log(data.children);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are only creating one object, then updating it, wheras you want 1 object in object.children for each item in the array "childArr" ...

```
data.children = [];
//object for child
var obj = {};
for (var j=0; j<childArr.length; j++) {
    var obj = {
        marker: childArr[j].split(" ")[0],
        value: childArr[j].substr(childArr[j].indexOf(' ')+1) 
    };
    data.children.push(obj);                  
}
```

Or did I miss something?

Comment: you missed javascript object literal syntax 101 :p

Comment: there you go (also, loose the = {} outside the loop, and the var inside the loop and you're golden :p

Comment: @War i tried your suggestion but getting `SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var childArr = [ 'ft Some older versions read, ',
      'fqa And we are writing these things to you so that your joy will be complete. ',
      'fqb  ',
      'f*' ];
    var data = {};
    data.children = [];

    for (var j=0; j<childArr.length; j++) {
        var dataArr = childArr[j].split(" ");
        var obj = {};
        obj.marker = dataArr[0];
        obj.value = (dataArr.length > 1) ? childArr[j].substr(childArr[j].indexOf(' ')+1) : "";
        data.children.push(obj);              
    }

    console.log(data.children);
```

Try this code. Its working

Otherwise you can Check in [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tstjq173/)

Comment: i have tried this but was giving me `Error while reading file.`

Comment: @zachi added JS fiddle link. Check there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over all the array elements.Find the index of first space to separate keys and values of new objects.

```js
   var array =     [ 'ft Some older versions read, ',
      'fqa And we are writing these things to you so that your joy will be complete. ',
      'fqb  ',
      'f*' ];
   var finalArray =[] ;
   array.forEach(function(value,index){
   var firstSpace = value.indexOf(' ');
   if(firstSpace >=0){
   var key = value.substr(0,firstSpace);
   var val = value.substr(firstSpace+1);
   }
   else{
   var key = value;
   var val = '';
   }
   var obj = {};
   obj.marker = key;
   obj.value = val;
   finalArray.push(obj);
  
   });
  console.log(finalArray);
```

Comment: but a remark, the last object came as this ` { marker: '', value: 'f*' } ` which i know to fix.

Comment: try edited answer.just make `if/else` condition for checking space.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var childArr = ['ft Some older versions read, ',
    'fqa And we are writing these things to you so that your joy will be complete. ',
    'fqb  ',
    'f*'
  ],
  data = {
    children: []
  };
for (var j = 0; j < childArr.length; j++) {
  let split = childArr[j].split(" ");
  data.children.push({
    marker: split[0],
    value: split.slice(1, -1).join(" ")
  });
}

console.log(data.children);
```